# How to set home directory mount point for drive

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, drive

I have 2 drives on my machine, but one is unused. I would like to use the unused drive for the home partition (as in moving my current home directory into the unused drive). Is this possible without reinstallation and if so how do I go about doing it?

Comment: To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving  I prefer to keep /home inside my / since on SSD. But had (until new larger SSD) all data in a separate /mnt/data partition on HDD. HDD now is mostly for backup and test installs. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: Why do that and not put the directories on that 2nd partition? the method to do that is already provided by the desktop. /home itself benefits from a speedy ssd if 1 of the 2 is an ssd. see `./config/users-dir.dirs`. Oh and moving /home/ to a NTFS will destroy your system. Only use ext.

Answer (score 1):

During this process, you should avoid using directory `/home` by any application, so it's best to not login from GUI, but from the text console (available after pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3 key).

Perform everything with root permissions (run `sudo -i` first).

Create a partition on the unused drive (using `fdisk`) and format it (create a filesystem) using `mkfs`.

Rename directory `/home` to `/old_home`. Create a new, empty
directory `/home`, with the same owner and permissions as `/old_home`.

Mount the new partition you just formatted under `/home`, For example if the new partition is `/dev/sdb1`, use the command `mount /dev/sdb1 /home`.

Copy everything from `/old_home` to `/home`, preserving ownership, permissions etc. (you may use `rsync` for that as mentioned in the comment above: `rsync -a /old_home/ /home/`).

Edit `/etc/fstab` file so that your new `/home` will be automatically mounted when the system reboots. Your `/etc/fstab` currently contains a line for the drive you are already using, it might be something like this (I'm making this one up now, yours may be different):

```
/dev/sda1 / ext4 defaults 0 1
```

Add a similar line for your new partition that says for example:

```
/dev/sdb1 /home ext4 defaults 0 2
```

(if your file has something else instead of "defaults" just copy these parameters to the new line).

Reboot your system (`shutdown -r now`) and after reboot check if everything is working properly (ie. everything that should be under `/home` is there). If yes, then delete the `/old_home` directory - it's not needed anymore.

Comment: Answer is woefully incomplete if you do not include details on how to copy the old home preserving all permissions. Using device descriptors in fstab is outdated and may not reliably work on modern systems.